# datetime.date values in a dictionary in Python change format when I print the whole dictionary as a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are datetime.dates. If I print the value as a string before it goes in the dict, it is hyphen separated. If I access the value from the dictionary and print as a string, it is hyphen separated. If I print the whole dictionary (as a string or not), the value is a comma separated date.

I already know I can workaround this by doing a for loop over the keys/values, and printing each in turn, but I want to understand what is happening. Why does this happen? The value itself is correct, but seems to change format when the dictionary is printed. I am using Python 2.7.

Thankyou! (First ever question so please forgive bad etiquette)

```
from datetime import datetime

date1 = '2014-07-09'

datesdict = {}

datetimeparse = datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d')
dateparse = datetime.date(datetimeparse)
datesdict['mykey'] = dateparse

print date1
print datetimeparse
print str(datetimeparse)
print dateparse
print str(dateparse)
print datesdict['mykey']
print str(datesdict['mykey'])  # <- I realise I am labouring the point a bit here
print datesdict
print str(datesdict)
```

This codes outputs:

```
2014-07-09
2014-07-09 00:00:00
2014-07-09 00:00:00
2014-07-09
2014-07-09
2014-07-09 # <- this should be *exactly* what is printed in the print dict command
2014-07-09
{'mykey': datetime.date(2014, 7, 9)}  # <- Why comma separated? Looking for an
{'mykey': datetime.date(2014, 7, 9)}  # <- explanation rather than a solution, please.
```

Comment: print calls `str` while dict's str conversion uses `repr` on its values.

Comment: There is the critical piece of information, thankyou! So str(mydict) is not actually str(mydict) but repr(mydict). annoying, but good to know.

Comment: What would be really annoying is if strings weren't quoted in dicts. Any time we want internal data represented in a particular way, we gotta expect to format it ourselves.

Comment: I have the same issue with you. Hope to have a solution too.

Answer (score 1):

As [you and jonatan pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222436/datetime-date-values-in-a-dictionary-in-python-change-format-when-i-print-the-wh#comment81396132_47222436), date value in a dict will be printed using `repr()` not `str()`, which result as `datetime.date(2014, 7, 9)` and `2014-07-09` accordingly

```
print repr(datesdict['mykey']) #datetime.date(2014, 7, 9)
print  str(datesdict['mykey']) #2014-07-09
```